# Query json in python

Tags: python, json

I am new to this. I am trying to get "VpcId" from the following JSON. Was trying to use get() method in python to do this. Can anybody help? Thank you in advance.

`ec2.describe_vpcs().get('Vpcs').get('VpcId')`

JSON Body trying to query

```
{
  "Vpcs": [
    {
      "CidrBlock": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "VpcId": "vpc-XXXXXXXXXX",
      "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
        {
          "AssociationId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
          "CidrBlock": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        }
      ],
      "IsDefault": XXXXXXXXXX,
    },
    {
      "CidrBlock": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "VpcId": "vpc-XXXXXXXXXX",
      "CidrBlockAssociationSet": [
        {
          "AssociationId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
          "CidrBlockState": {
            "State": "XXXXXXXXXX"
          }
        }
      ],
      "IsDefault": XXXXXXXXXX,
    },
    "ResponseMetadata": {
      },
      "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which `VpcId`? There are multiple.

Comment: What's the error you are facing while using `get`?

Comment: all the 'VpcId'. Error is

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' `

Comment: has the JSON been converted to a python dictionary at some point? Understand, JSON is a text format which gets read as a string. to get a value, you have to convert it to a dictionary (example: `json.loads(stringvalue)`. It's not clear if that's been done or not.

Comment: I have tried   `json.dumps(ec2.describe_vpcs()).get('Vpcs').get('VpcId')` . Gave the ssame error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

You should iter through `Vpcs`. Try the following:

```
for i in ec2.describe_vpcs().get('Vpcs'):
    print(i.get('VpcId'))
```

Since there are more than one results you have to loop them but you can also do it in one line:

```
print('\n'.join(i.get('VpcId') for i in ec2.describe_vpcs().get('Vpcs')))
```

Answer (score 1):

- `ec2.describe_vpcs().get('Vpcs')` give you an array. Array does not have attribute get. Plus, your json format is not correct, you miss one `]` at the end
- You should loop through it and then you can use `.get('VpcId')`